# AWS Cognito User Pool and Account ID

Tags: security, single-page-application, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to design an enterprise application with different accounts and users.
What's the best way to map users to account ID then control their resource access?
Assuming I store account ID in dynamo DB and use AppSync to access data?

e.g. user 1 belongs to account A and can only access information for account A through an angular SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

1. store Account ID in a custom Cognito User Pool attribute, or
2. you can save User Pool's User ID <-> Account ID mapping in Dynamo DB.

Either way, upon API request you can now find requester's associated account ID, depending on where you stored the mapping:

1. from ID token's custom attribute
2. make a request to DynamoDB to find out mapping for given user ID (`sub` field in ID or Access token).

Knowing Account ID associated with the user, you can make authorization decision in your Appsync resolver (or Lambda authorizer, if that's possible).